# SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED certificate verify failed: self-signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1129)

Tags: python, ssl, pip, ssl-certificate, warnings

Good afternoon friends,

Every time I try to install something via an external link via `pip` I get a lot of errors and warnings, but then it still starts downloading what I need. How to make it download immediately without WARNING notifications? How can I overcome certificate verification on my device ?

```
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self-signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1129)'))': /releases/repo.html
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self-signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1129)'))': /releases/repo.html
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self-signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1129)'))': /releases/repo.html
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self-signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1129)'))': /releases/repo.html
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self-signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1129)'))': /releases/repo.html
Could not fetch URL https://modelscope.oss-cn-beijing.aliyuncs.com/releases/repo.html: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='modelscope.oss-cn-beijing.aliyuncs.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /releases/repo.html (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self-signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1129)'))) - skipping
```

I was finding a solution https://discuss.python.org/t/ssl-certificate-verify-failed-certificate-verify-failed-self-signed-certificate/14359 but it didn't help, or I did something wrong.

Comment: There are many similar questions here. It is very likely that your problem is solved by one of these. *".... but it didn't help, or I did something wrong."* - this statement unfortunately says nothing about what exactly you did, so it is not helpful at all to narrow down the cause of your problem.